# D3.js heatmap for json data

Tags: json, d3.js, heatmap

I am learning D3, and I am trying to build a heat map.
I am referring this: http://bl.ocks.org/ianyfchang/8119685

I have data in JSON format

```
var data=[{
        “id“:”0006ki01”,
        “exp1”:0.76,
        ”exp2”:0.56,
        ”exp3”:0.005,
        ”exp4”:0.007
},
{
        “id“:”0006ki02”,
        exp1”:0.006,
        ”exp2”:0.46,
        ”exp3”:0.003,
        ”exp4”:0.008
}
.
.
.

]
```

In x axis experiments and y-axis all genes, and values of each experiments will determine colour of the cell.

How can I achieve this?

Gene ids on y axis, Experiments on x axis, values of each experiments will determine the colour of each cell.

Below code draws first column of heatmap(index of each object in data for y attribute, and 0 for x) But how can I draw for whole data I have?

```
 var heatmap= svg.append("g") 
             .selectAll(".cell")
             .data(data)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x",0)    //Here how can I get experiment index?
             .attr("y", function(d,i){ return i * cellSize;}
             .attr("width",cellSize)
             .attr("height",cellSize)
             .style("fill",function(d){ return colorScale(d.exp1)//This gets data from exp1 but how to get values for each experiment?
```

Comment: Have you used your favorite search engine and try: `d3 heat map`

Comment: @rioV8 yes, I couldn't find solution. it would be great if you can explain me how can I go further.I also added a chunk of code which explains the issue I have. Thanks

Comment: what is `experiment index`? Explain what you want along the X-axis and the Y-axis and based on what fields it is calculated.

Comment: @rioV8 I edited my question with detail, for X-axis value: index of  experiments i.e index of "exp1","exp2" etc, for Y-axis value, index of each object in 'data'

Comment: Still not very clear but is `0006ki02` a gene id and is `0.46` a value of an experiment, and 1 in `exp1` is your x-axis index. Maybe parse the string to extract the number `Number(str.replace('exp','')`

Comment: You need to transform your data with the `expX` values into an array or denormalize the data and construct records containing: geneId, x-index, y-index and value